# Moment.js Add time to string input

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am wanting to convert a string into a moment and then add +5 hours and output the result to a new var

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/ - Had a look here and from what I have below I would expect it to work but the console log is showing null. Can anyone spot where I am going wrong? Thanks

```
var input = "2020-08-06 15:15:00"

var manDate = moment(input, "YYYY MM DD hh mm ss")
var b = manDate.add(5, 'hours'); 
console.log(b)
```

***edit
Expected output should be `2020-08-06 20:15:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format it correctly on the `moment(input,format)`

```js
var input = "2020-08-06 15:15:00"

var manDate = moment(input, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")

var b = manDate.add(5, 'hour'); 
console.log(b.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input format does not match your input string. Otherwise, `manDate` is an invalid date upon creation.

`var input = "2020-08-06 15:15:00"`

Your input format should match that, so it would be:

`var manDate = moment(input, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: hh means 12am/pm format so it wouldn't work for this case.

Comment: @Carlos1232 Edited to match, but using hh didn't seem to affect it when I ran it in my browser. The added values were still correct and displaying as if it was a 24 hour format.

Comment: You're right was my bad, but you won't know what time it is correctly unless you format it to "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a"

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to the [moment function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) is the format. It should match the string date chars and any other used (ex: "/", "-", ":"). You should use `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` OR leave it empty as this format is default. To output the moment variable to a string use the [format method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) with the desired output format as the first argument.

```
var input = "2020-08-06 15:15:00"
var manDate = moment(input);
var b = manDate.add(5, 'hours');
console.log(b.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'));
```